# Column added to view not getting picked up by Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I added a new column `MyColumn` to `vwMyView` in `MyDB`. `MyDB` has a stored procedure `MySproc` which returns `vwMyView.*` in a select statement.

When I execute `MySproc`, `vwMyView.MyColumn` is included in the result set. However, when I recreate my EF6 `.edmx` data model, `MyColumn` is not reflected in the EF `vwMyView` object or in `MySproc_Result`.

Is there a special trick I need to use so my new column `MyColumn` is reflected in a recreated EF6 `.edmx`?  Is this a quirk that you encounter sometimes?

Comment: I think you need to update *.edmx file by right clicking on it

Comment: I deleted the edmx file completely and then recreated it

Comment: @user9393635 verify your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Happens sometimes, especially when the output is generated runtime as a polymorphic behavior (different result sets based on conditions)

In EF, for a result set, you **may** need to explictly create an output mapping. No need to delete the whole EDMX, just select the mapping (MySproc_Result) and update the result set to include the new column.

Are you creating the view inside procedure and then returning its value?

Inside the view, check if the columns are added conditionally (eg, if type=Sales, include 4 columns, if type=Mgmt, include 5 columns). The EF will pick up the 1st matching case in this condition.

Best way is to update the mapping and have the new column set as nullable, just in case some conditional makes it unavailable.